# Why use Func<> in controller constructor parameters in MVVM applications

Tags: wpf, mvvm, prism

I'm seeing, more and more code like the code below in an MVVM application (WPF and Prism). Controllers have the following code fragments:

```
public class DispenseOptionController : IDispenseOptionController
{
    protected readonly Func<IPharmacyCdmServiceSimpleClient> CdmClient;

    protected readonly Func<IPatientServiceSimpleClient> PatientClient;

    public DispenseOptionController(Func<IPharmacyCdmServiceSimpleClient> cdmClient, Func<IPatientServiceSimpleClient> patientClient)
    {
        CdmClient = cdmClient;
        PatientClient = patientClient;
    }...
```

I'm trying to understand the role that Func<> plays here. It seems that this delegate is used as parameters to the constructor. Can someone explain to me why anyone would use Func<> in this particular case? And can Func<> be replaced with anything else?

Answer (score 0):

A `Func<>` is nothing but the Encapsulation of a method that one or more parameter and returns a value of the type specified by the TResult parameter.

You could see some use cases [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/27582/Fun-with-Func)

Comment: That part I understand. I guess I'd like to know why Func would be used instead of an interface and use say, an IOC to inject the parameters. Why this way over the other?